# return reference in cpp function returns a copy

Tags: c++, reference, return-value

I am trying to return the reference of the argument in the function `test`, but when I assign another value to the returned reference, the original doesn't change:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int& test(int& n) {
    return n;
}

int main() {
    int n = 1;
    int m = test(n);
    m = 2;
    cout << n << endl; // n = 1
    return 0;
}
```

How can I return this reference as I expect?

This testing is just for studying purposes.

Comment: `m` is not a reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `m` an lvalue reference:

```
 int& m = test(n);
```

You can also bind to temporaries like this:

```
int test(int& n) { // return by value
    return n;
}

int main() {
    int n = 1;
    int&& m = test(n); // rvalue reference binding to a copy of `n`
    m = 2;
    std::cout << n << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Although the above code is not recommended.

Or even this:

```
int&& test( int& n ) // return by rvalue reference
{
    return std::move( n ); // cast `n` from lvalue to xvalue
}

int main( )
{
    int n = 1;
    int&& m = test(n);
    m = 2;
    std::cout << n << std::endl;
}
```

This one is also not recommended. Instead of rvalue reference, you should return by value.

Comment: I'm not sure what your second example [is supposed to demonstrate](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1FBdOPy5wyS7mBqs).

Comment: @Paul Sanders *Educational* info.

Comment: But with the 2nd example we lose the reference and have a copy at the end.

Comment: @Sebastian Yes, added the description for that in a comment.

Answer (score 4):

The line

```
int m = test(n);
```

creates a copy of the value `test(n)` returns (in this case a copy of `n`).

If you want a reference to the return value of `test(n)` you have to use one:

```
int& m = test(n);
```

A common caveat occurs with type inference using `auto`: Even in this case you would have to use

```
auto& m = test(n);
```

Comment: Good advice with `auto`!